# Sum of an attribute from all objects in a core data entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating an app for making bookkeeping at my school easier. I have a club tableView which is followed by a member tableView and a transaction table View hierarchical. The user can add a new member with his amount of money at the start and add transactions to this member. Now I want to show in the tableView the total amount of money which the member has. So I have to build the sum of all his transactions from core data and his money at the start. I saw a lot of examples, but not for my case with Core-data. So my question is: How can I calculate the sum of all attributes from these core data objects.
[Core-Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2nue.png)

Comment: show you .xcdatamodel file

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal I added it to the question

Comment: so u want to add money attribute of all trans for a particular user. right ??

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw transactions is set of transactions managedObject.Create a variable called count and run a for loop and add money.

```
var count = 0
for trans in member.transtion {
     count = trans.money + count
}
```

Comment: It worked :D Is there a way, how I can display this to the cell of the specific member. I have there at the moment just the start amount of money?